# Использование JSON в Android

Tags: java, android, json

**Описание:**
Я делаю небольшое  приложение отображающие маркеры но возникла проблема с использованием JSON.

**Проблема:** я не понимаю как осуществить передачу  данных из файла , для последующего создания маркеров на их основе.Большинство примеров которые я находил были для передачи данных с сайтов( Я новичок, делаю для android в Android studio вот пример:

**.json:**

```
  {
  "markerss":[
  {
    "title": "West",
    "lat": 53.223798,
    "lng": 44.889040,
    "snippet": "placeinformation2010"
  },
  {
    "title": "East",
    "lat": 53.2220,
    "lng": 44.8799,
    "snippet": "placeinformation102"
  }
]
 }
```

**.java:**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback {

     GoogleMap mMap = null;

    private static final LatLng place1 = new LatLng(53.223798, 44.889040);
    private static final LatLng place2 = new LatLng(53.2220, 44.8799);


    // Решил попробовать сделать перемененные для последующей и работы ,тип  ближайшей 

    Marker mPlace1;
    Marker mPlace2;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(41.889, -87.622), 10));


        // Создание  маркеров и подробная их подробная информация

        mPlace1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(place1)
                .title("West")
                .anchor(0.0f, 1.0f)
               .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.kebab))
                .snippet("dsf"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(place1));


        mPlace2 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(place2)
                .title("East")
                .anchor(0.0f, 1.0f)
               .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.kebab))
               .snippet("edfjk"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(place2));

  }

}
```

Comment: хотелось бы узнать на каком именно этапе у Вас возникает проблема и С ЧЕМ ИМЕННО Вас возникла проблема: чтение из файла?

Comment: Совершенно верно, проблема с чтением файла и расстановкой маркеров по данным значениями.

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вы хотите хранить `JSON` строку в памяти телефона и работать локально.

В таком случае вы должны хранить ваш файл `coordinates.json` в папке `assets` и оттуда считывать при необходимости.

Вот вам метод для получения `JSON` строки из папки `assets`:

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        String json = null;
        try {
            InputStream is = getActivity().getAssets().open("coordinates.json");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;
    }
```

Этот метод возвращает строку `Json`, то есть можете присвоить к своему переменному, например:

```
String coordinatesJson = loadJSONFromAsset();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(coordinatesJson);
```

И дальше распарсить `jsonObject`

Пример:

```
    String coordinatesJson = loadJSONFromAsset();

    JSONObject jsonObject;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(coordinatesJson);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("markerss");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String title = jsonObject.getString("title"));
            Double lat = jsonObject.getDouble("lat"));
            Double lon = jsonObject.getDouble("lon"));
            String snippet = jsonObject.getString("snippet"));
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Попробуйте, на этом редакторе написал, главное вы поняли суть...

Comment: предположу, что для окончательного решения задачи, скорее всего также потребуется преобразования json-строки в объект.

Comment: Вы правы ,я предполагаю ,что json-строки можно будет использовать для создания маркеров на карте.

Comment: Так то уже написал. Используйте Double lat для Latitude и lon как Longitude.